# Is this kind of login possible in VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I work on Access Project, but I think there is nothing specific to Access in this question.

I have a form and it's possible to open it only if you are in the table of authenticated users (and I authenticate user by his windows username) - I know it is lame authentication.

Here's the code I've put into form open event:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

If DCount("User_Id", "Users", "[username]='" & (Environ$("Username")) & "'") Then

Else
    MsgBox "Access Denied!"
    DoCmd.Quit

End If

End Sub
```

What I want to accomplish is that when `MsgBox "Access Denied!"` is displayed, if I type certain word (something as password) before clicking on OK button, that `DoCmd.Quit` is not executed. I don't want to display anything, just type in the password.

I don't need this desperately, I just want to make this for fun. And I think it would be really cool if it's possible with VBA.

Comment: I don't really think this is possible. Message boxes are displayed in a manner that doesn't really allow for user input, other than the Buttons.  While I would think it *maybe* possible to use the `WinAPI` to catch keystrokes, I am pretty sure this *can't* be done while the message box is displayed because code is *running* and VBA doesn't really do multi-threading to allow a listener to trap keystrokes while the other code is actively executing.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this in Access 2007 and I think the logic is what you want, or at least it's close.  Please consider using something like the `WindowsUser()` function below to get the Windows user name.  I get that this is just for fun, so you don't care now.  However, keep this point in mind for anything you do care about in the future.  `Environ("USERNAME")` as a security measure is trivially easy to defeat.

```vba
Const cstrYourPassword As String = "let me in"
Dim blnGoodbye As Boolean
Dim lngButtons As Long
Dim strPrompt As String
Dim strPassword As String

strPrompt = "Access Denied!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "Click Retry to try with password" & vbCrLf & _
    "or Cancel to quit."
lngButtons = vbCritical + vbRetryCancel
If MsgBox(strPrompt, lngButtons) = vbRetry Then
    strPassword = InputBox("Password:")
    If strPassword = cstrYourPassword Then
        MsgBox "Welcome " & WindowsUser
    Else
        blnGoodbye = True
    End If
Else
    blnGoodbye = True
End If

If blnGoodbye = True Then
    MsgBox "That's all folks."
    'DoCmd.Quit ' <- enable this when ready.
End If
```

Use this instead of `Environ("USERNAME")`.

```vba
Public Function WindowsUser() As String
    Static strUserName As String

    If Len(strUserName) = 0 Then
        strUserName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").Username
    End If
    WindowsUser = strUserName
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, but you may want to modify it to set the password to something better or if you want more than one password. Anyone who knows how to read the code will be able to find out the password as well, so maybe it would be better to put it in the database somewhere?

```
Const sPassword As String = "PASSWORD"
Const sMESSAGE As String = "Please enter your password"
Const sTITLE As String = "Enter Password"
Dim sInput As String

sInput = InputBox(sMESSAGE, sTITLE)

If sInput <> Password Then
    MsgBox "Access Denied!"
    DoCmd.Quit
End If
```